# Magnitude of translational acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rotation

> The angular speed of a point following a circular path with radius r=0.171 m can be described by the equation:
>
> ω=8.79t+8.59 rad/s.
>
> At t=1.50 s, what is the magnitude of the translation acceleration in $m/s^2$?

I am a bit confused, do I use **$a=r\alpha$** or **$a=r\omega^2$**? I'm not really sure if this is centripetal acceleration or tangential acceleration or whatever they're asking for. Thanks :)

Comment: Translation means moving (and not rotating). So, I would just vectorially add the centripetal and tangential acceleration, which is easy to do since they are perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point has centripetal acceleration towards the centre of its circular path and tangential acceleration along a tangent to its path. These are at right angles to each other so can be added using Pythagoras' theorem:

a(r)=ω^2*r

just substitute t=1.50 s
into the original equation to get ω.

The tangential acceleration can be calculated with

a(t)=α*r.

The angular acceleration was calculated in the first part, then:

a=sqrt(a(r)^2+a(t)^2)